# How do you integrate adverts with a Canvas view

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas, mobclix

How do you integrate adverts with a `Canvas` view, I am using `mobclix`, I want the `mobclix` layout so it appears above the `Canvas` view. I use the canvas for a game. Can you give code example please.

Comment: Have you tried using RelativeLayout which uses zIndex according to the appearance in the code?

Comment: Hi, yes im using the RelativeLayout I am using setContentView() in the Activity to display the layout. setContentView(R.layout.main) for the main android xml layout and setContentView(_panelView) for the canvas view. I can get it so that either the mobclix advertisement appears or the canvas layout but not both together, any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! setContentView in the same activity will SET the content, not ADD.

What you have to do is (in your Activity!):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID_TO_YOUR_RELATIVE_LAYOUT_ELEMENT);
r.addView(_panelView);
```